# merging 2 verbs such as 返す and 遅れる into 返し遅れる?

Tags: verbs

Merging two verbs into one is a common structure:
繰り返す、書き直す、思い出す、乗り換える、etc.
sometimes the new verb mixes the meaning of the 2 verbs as well, sometimes not.

What about merging 2 verbs into a new verb on an ad hoc basis? This new verb does not exist in a dictionary. But, the mixed meaning of the new verb conveys the meaning I want. For example:

I received an email last week that I overlooked. Today I responded. I wanted to say "to reply late". The "mixed verb" I created is "返し遅れる"

> 先週のemailを送って頂きまして誠にありがとございました。大変、**返し遅れて**恐縮でございます。

Does **返し遅れる** work here? Can you take the liberty to merge verbs and create verbs that don't exist in dictionaries?

**example #2**
走り逃げる
I'd think this means "*to escape by running.*"

So, can you merge verbs like this "*when it makes sense and the meaning is clear*"?

Comment: "*Can you take the liberty to merge verbs and create verbs that don't exist in dictionaries?*" -- can you take the liberty to create words that don't exist in English dictionaries? Do "verbmerging," "compleverbing," or "combipredicate" make sense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 先週のemailを送って頂きまして誠にありがとございました。大変、返し遅れて恐縮でございます。

I think this one is a bit awkward because of the formality. Between you and your friends, I don't think so many people make a fuss about 「返し遅れて」itself.

According to the 「NWJCコーパス」,

[「返し遅れて」](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/nwjc/string_search?commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&string_search%5Burl_domain%5D=&string_search%5Bwords%5D=%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E9%81%85%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6&utf8=%E2%9C%93) has *305 hits.*

I think the verb is used in the blogs, social networking services, etc. since it is used like「"コメント"返し遅れて」& ごめん, すみません, 申し訳ございません or something like that. So, it is bit casual and「ご返事が遅れ」or 「返信が遅くなり」is more appropriate to your sentence.

(As a side note: I think 大変 should be put just before「恐縮」if you want to emphasize apology).

[「走り逃げる」](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/nwjc/string_search?commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&string_search%5Burl_domain%5D=&string_search%5Bwords%5D=%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8A%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B&utf8=%E2%9C%93) has only *72 hits.* So, it is still casual and has not widely been used so far.

[「走って逃げる」](https://bonten.ninjal.ac.jp/nwjc/string_search?commit=%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2&string_search%5Burl_domain%5D=&string_search%5Bwords%5D=%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8A%E5%8E%BB%E3%82%8B&utf8=%E2%9C%93) has *2270 hits* and it should be more natural and widely used.

The language has been changing all the time and I am not sure about the future though, the statistics shows some combination of verbs does not work really well at the moment.